# Leaflet/HTML/GeoJSON: How to put a pop-up on a geoJSON point?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, html

I don't have much knowledge of HTML/JS/GeoJSON, and have made a webmap from trial and error with many different tutorials. I have tried leaflet's tutorials but cannot get the desired results.

I have a functioning Leaflet webmap that shows GeoJSON points. I need to symbolize the points based on GeoJSON properties, and provide a pop-up when the point is clicked. I can use "pointToLayer" to turn the default blue markers into a custom point,

[image]

but when I try to incorporate a pop-up, the blue points turn back into default markers

[image]

How can I get a custom-symbolized point with a pop-up? What am I doing wrong?

Here is the HTML code I am using:

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
radius: 5,
fillColor: "#33ccff",
color: "#000",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.9
};

$.getJSON("./geojson/kitchener_sidewalks2.geojson",  
 function(data) {
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {onEachFeature: action_To_Perform_When_Marker_Is_Clicked_On_The_Map},
       {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
        }
    });
    geojson.addTo(map);
    myGeoJSONLayers.addLayer(geojson);
 });



var overlayMaps = {"Kitchener Sidewalk Issues": myGeoJSONLayers};   

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps,myGeoJSONLayers).addTo(map); 

function action_To_Perform_When_Marker_Is_Clicked_On_The_Map(feature, layer) {
if (feature.properties)
{
    var PopupText = []; 
    PopupText.push("<b>Accessibility Issue: </b>" + feature.properties.Issue);
    PopupText.push("<b><br/>Description: </b>" + feature.properties.Descriptio);
    PopupText.push("<b><br/>Recorded: </b>" + feature.properties.CreationDa)
    layer.bindPopup("<p>" + PopupText.join("") + "</p>");                       
} 
}
```

Comment: Check the browser console for errors - that should help find our where the problem is (press F12 to open the browser dev tools and click on the Console tab). But MappaGnosis is right about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I typically call `pointToLayer` before I call `onEachFeature`.

Also I `return new L.circleMarker()` where you `return L.circleMarker()`

Thats not an answer to your question but its what I do with almost the same exact scenario and it works for me.

ie:

```
geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(json, {
      pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
       return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 10, fillOpacity: 0.0, weight: 0});
      },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
       var str = (feature ?
        '<b>' + ((feature.properties.mh_no == null) ? "Manhole" : "Manhole " + feature.properties.mh_no)  + '</b>' +
        '<br /><b>Northing: </b>' + ((feature.properties.northing == 0) ? "" : feature.properties.northing) + 
        '<br /><b>Easting: </b>' + ((feature.properties.easting == 0) ? "" : feature.properties.easting) + 
        '<br /><b>Elevation: </b>' + ((feature.properties.elevation == 0) ? "" : feature.properties.elevation) + 
        '<br /><b>Bottom: </b>' + ((feature.properties.bottom == null) ? "" : feature.properties.bottom) + 
        '<br /><b>Diameter: </b>' + ((feature.properties.diameter == null) ? "" : feature.properties.diameter) +    
        '<br /><b>Subdivision: </b>' + ((feature.properties.subdivision == null) ? "" : feature.properties.subdivision) + 
        '<br /><b>Platbook: </b>' + ((feature.properties.platbook == null) ? "" : feature.properties.platbook) + 
        '<br /><b>Age: </b>' + ((feature.properties.age == null) ? "" : feature.properties.age) + 
        '<br /><b>Date Inspected: </b>' + ((feature.properties.date_inspect == null) ? "" : feature.properties.date_inspect) + 
        '<br /><b>Date Installed: </b>' + ((feature.properties.date_install == null) ? "" : feature.properties.date_install) +
        '<br /><b>Comments: </b>' + ((feature.properties.comments == null) ? "" : feature.properties.comments)
        : '');
       layer.bindPopup(str);
      }
```

Comment: Trying to make these changes!
Instead of the large "var str = (feature ?" block, what could I put there in order to make a pop-up appear from my properties? I've tried putting in my "var PopupText = []; " block instead but it didn't work.

Comment: perhaps your issue all along was the missing ; on the third feature property push. I think your code is fine otherwise. i'm no expert tho

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it. Still only showing the default markers

Comment: Note how PointToLayer is NOT within its own curly braces here (where as yours incorrectly is)

Answer (score 0):

I think the trouble may simply be the formatting of your `options` block. Based on how I'm understanding [Leaflet's documentation for GeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson), both `onEachFeature` and `pointToLayer` should be attributes of the same `options` object. What happens if you format it like this?

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: action_To_Perform_When_Marker_Is_Clicked_On_The_Map,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }   
});
```

The way you have the code in your original post, I would *expect* your `pointToLayer` attribute is getting orphaned--in other words, Leaflet's GeoJSON class doesn't see it among the `options` keys, so it just leaves it hanging.

Comment: Actually, this removes all of my points from the map. The GeoJSON data is not showing up anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

onEachFeature  is what your missing, this is what I have used in my apps.

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions3 = {
        radius: 8,
        color: "yellow",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
};

geojsonLayer3 = L.geoJson(response5, {
            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng,  geojsonMarkerOptions3 );
            },
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("<p>Record: " + feature.properties.Record +  "</br>Address: " + feature.properties.FullAdd + "</br> Quad: "+feature.properties.Quad + "</p>");
            }
            });

            map.addLayer(geojsonLayer3);
            }
```